# Getting results between two datetimepickers to listview from xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem with result filtering.

I have a xml file:

```
<Person>
    <Client>
        <Name>JOHN</Name>
        <Sname>DOE</Sname>
        <Birthdate>12/23/1985</Birthdate>
        <City>Gjakove</City>
        <RegistrationDate>06/01/2014</RegistrationDate>
    </Client>
    <Client>
        <Name>Tim</Name>
        <Sname>DOE</Sname>
        <Birthdate>12/23/1995</Birthdate>
        <City>Gjakove</City>
        <RegistrationDate>01/01/2014</RegistrationDate>
    </Client>
</Person>
```

And I want to filter my results in listview by selecting dates in two datetimepickers.
For example

> DateTimePickerFROM : 01/06/2013
>
> DateTimePickerTO: 10/10/2014

Comment: ListView and xml file... Is there something in between?

Comment: Filter By `RegistrationDate` or `Birthdate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string xmlStr = @"<Root>
                    <Person>
                      <Name>JOHN</Name>
                      <Sname>DOE</Sname>
                      <Birthdate>12/23/1985</Birthdate>
                      <City>Gjakove</City>
                      <RegistrationDate>06/01/2014</RegistrationDate>
                    </Person>
                    <Person>
                      <Name>Tim</Name>
                      <Sname>DOE</Sname>
                      <Birthdate>12/23/1995</Birthdate>
                      <City>Gjakove</City>
                      <RegistrationDate>01/01/2014</RegistrationDate>
                    </Person>
                  </Root>";


var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);

var q = from el in doc.Root.Elements("Person")
        let date = DateTime.Parse(el.Element("RegistrationDate").Value)
        where date >= DateTimePickerFROM.Value && date <= DateTimePickerTO.Value
        select new ListViewItem ( el.Elements().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray());

//add all filtered Presons elements
listView1.Items.AddRange(q.ToArray());
```

Comment: Yes but I want to filter from the XML file.

Comment: instead this: `var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);` write `var doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\YourFile.xml");`